# Improve my SQL Select statement to select students who have not fully completed a section

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

My SQL skills are quite limited. I'm in my second year of computer science at a technical college. I'm building a windows forms application that will allow the BAS director at my college to keep track of students and their progress throughout the courses. I have complete control over the database design so if you think of a way to help me reach a solution that would involve tweaking the database that is a possibility.

I'm trying to select all of the `Students` who do not have an `EnrollmentStatus` of 3 in all of the `Courses` that have a `CreditSection` of `1`. There are 12 courses with a `CreditSection` of `1`

The tables I'm using look like this:
[image: Schema]

I can think of a few ways to get my solution in speech, but can't seem to write them SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE each student has 12 entries in CourseEnrollment AND
CourseEnrollment.EnrollmentStatus = 3 AND Courses.CreditSection = 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Courses.CourseID 1 thru 12 EXIST in
CourseEnrollment for each student AND CourseEnrollment.EnrollmentStatus = 3
```

I can get to the desired solution using this mess below, but as I check for students who have completed 4 years worth of courses... this query becomes ridiculously long and probably mega resource consuming.

This query selects students who are not in the list of students who have completed one or more the given courses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* FROM Students s
WHERE s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 1 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 2 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 3 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 4 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 5 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 6 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 7 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 8 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 9 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 10 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 11 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 12 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3) OR
s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT ce.StudentID FROM CourseEnrollment ce WHERE ce.CourseID = 13 AND ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3)
```

My goal is to figure out how to write this query in SQL and then convert it to LINQ which is ultimately what I need. If anyone can help with either part of this I would be grateful.

I've converted the above to LINQ and it looks just as horrendous:

```
var query =
                from student in datStudents.Students.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.StudentsRow>()
                where !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 1 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 2 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 3 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 4 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 5 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 6 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 7 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 8 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 9 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 10 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 11 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 12 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID) ||
                !(from ce2 in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() where ce2.CourseID == 13 && ce2.EnrollmentStatus == 3 select ce2.Field<int>("StudentID")).Contains<int>(student.StudentID)
                select new
                {
                    id = student.StudentID,
                    rtcid = student.RTCStudentID,
                    firstname = student.FirstName,
                    lastname = student.LastName,
                    phone = student.Phone,
                    studentemail = student.StudentEmail,
                    personalemail = student.PersonalEmail,
                    address = student.Address,
                    city = student.City,
                    state = student.State,
                    zip = student.Zip,
                    birthdate = student.BirthDate,
                    gender = student.Gender,
                    notes = student.Notes,
                    studentdocumentslocation = student.StudentDocumentsLocation
                };
```

Comment: Just a general note on your database design - do you have some way to track terms?  Or are you wiping out old data with every term?  I also don't see fields in the enrollment table that support course withdrawals.

Comment: @Chris Schubert I still need to come up with a way to track the year that each student graduates from the program, I'm thinking of putting a field in each enrollment for completion date and the graduation year will be a query that `selects the last completion date in the list of courses a student has completed where the student has completed the required number of courses for each section` Withdraws should be handled by EnrollmentStatus which is fk to a lookup table that allows Enrollments to have the status of 'not enrolled, enrolled, completed, failed, dropped'

Advice is always welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a subquery with a group by and having statement you can come up with something similar to this:

```
 SELECT * FROM Students WHERE StudentID NOT IN (
      SELECT s.StudentID FROM Students s 
        JOIN CourseEnrollment ce ON s.StudentID = ce.StudentID
        JOIN Courses c ON ce.CourseID = c.CourseID
        WHERE ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3 AND c.CreditSection = 1
        GROUP BY s.StudentID
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 12
      )
```

The inner query builds the criteria for students to return, and the "HAVING COUNT(*) = 12" gets you students that match 12 courses. If you only a subset of courses, you can also try the following.

```
 SELECT * FROM Students WHERE StudentID NOT IN (
      SELECT s.StudentID FROM Students s 
        JOIN CourseEnrollment ce ON s.StudentID = ce.StudentID
        JOIN Courses c ON ce.CourseID = c.CourseID
        WHERE ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3 AND c.CreditSection = 1
        AND c.CourseID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
        GROUP BY s.StudentID
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 8 -- Number of courses in the ID in clause
      )
```

Hope this helps you get on track.

Comment: Thank you Martin and Carl, the first code block is exactly what I was looking for (after the edit xD) I can now see all students who have not completed the required courses including students who don't have any entries in CourseEnrollment

Comment: I'm glad that worked out for you. I was a bit tired last night so I missed the "not" in the statement, but glad Carl could help out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, I typed it by hand, so there could be a typo.

```html
SELECT * FROM Students s
 inner join (select StudentID, count(0) as CrsEnrollCount
     from CourseEnrollment ce 
     inner join Courses c 
     on ce.CourseID = c.CourseID
     where ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3 AND Courses.CreditSection = 1) cnt
 on cnt.StudentID = s.StudentID
where CrsEnrollCount < 12
```

Comment: This was helpful, but is missing a GROUP BY StudentID in the inner select statement. One issue with this is that some students have 0 entries into CourseEnrollment and those students do not get selected here.

Somehow I'm trying to also say `AND s.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT cnt.StudentID FROM cnt)` in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this T-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE StudentID NOT IN (
  SELECT s.StudentID FROM Students s 
    JOIN CourseEnrollment ce ON s.StudentID = ce.StudentID
    JOIN Courses c ON ce.CourseID = c.CourseID
    WHERE ce.EnrollmentStatus = 3 AND c.CreditSection = 1
    GROUP BY s.StudentID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 12
  )
```

Becomes this LINQ:

```
var query = 
            from student in datStudents.Students.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.StudentsRow>()
            where !(from s2 in datStudents.Students.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.StudentsRow>()
                        join ce in datStudents.CourseEnrollment.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CourseEnrollmentRow>() on student.StudentID equals ce.StudentID
                        join c in datStudents.Courses.AsEnumerable<dsStudentManager.CoursesRow>() on ce.CourseID equals c.CourseID
                        where ce.EnrollmentStatus == 3 && c.CreditSection == 1
                        group s2 by s2.StudentID into s3
                        where s3.Count() == 12
                        select s3.Key).Contains<int>(student.StudentID)
            select new
            {
                id = student.StudentID,
                rtcid = student.RTCStudentID,
                firstname = student.FirstName,
                lastname = student.LastName,
                phone = student.Phone,
                studentemail = student.StudentEmail,
                personalemail = student.PersonalEmail,
                address = student.Address,
                city = student.City,
                state = student.State,
                zip = student.Zip,
                birthdate = student.BirthDate,
                gender = student.Gender,
                notes = student.Notes,
                studentdocumentslocation = student.StudentDocumentsLocation
            };
```

As far as I can tell, this is correct. It produces the desired results anyway.